# Having difficulties to find the inner text of a specific Span from HTML string

Tags: jquery, find, each, html

I am new in Jquery having problem with identify a specific tag among an HTML string. My HTML string is :

```
<span id="name">myname</span>  
<span id="familyname">mysurname</span>     
<span id="telnum">mytelnum</span>  
<span id="postcode">myPostCode</span> 
<span id="email">my@email.com</span>
```

And what I want is having each span inner text in separated variable.

The expected outcome is:

```
var a = 'myname';
var b = 'mysurname';
var c = 'telnum';
var d = 'myPostCode';
var e = 'my@email.com';
```

but in my code it sounds that the find function is not working!
here is my code:

```
var myHtmlCode = '<span id="name"> myname</span> <span id="familyname">mysurname</span> <span id="telnum"> mytelnum</span><span id="postcode"> myPostCode</span><span id="email">my@email.com</span>';

var $temp = $(myHtmlCode).find('span').contents().each(function() {
    alert(this.val());  
});
```

any helps is appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following piece of code:

```
var $temp = $(myHtmlCode).each(function () {

            if (this.id == "name") {

            alert(this.innerHTML);
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `contents`, it's useless here, as you can call the `text` function from the `span` elements.

And if you want to be able to explore the parsed string, you must embed the spans in one top level element.

You can put the texts in an object like this :

```
var texts = {};
$('<div>'+myHtmlCode+'</div>').find('span')
  .each(function(){ texts[this.id] = $(this).text() });
```

Then you can read a text as, for example, `texts.name`.

[**Demonstration**](http://jsbin.com/usapum/1/edit) (open the console to see the `texts` object).

Of course you could as well do it as global variables, that is using `window.name` instead of `texts.name`, but it's really recommended to avoid cluttering the global name space.

Comment: Dystory, Thanks for the help.

Comment: The outcome of your sample is [object Object]. Can you find the source of problem?

Comment: Did you try to `alert` it ? Don't. [Use the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: It worked fine with this alert : 
alert(this.innerHTML)

But I used it for another html code and it does not working for this new one, here is the new html code:

Comment: <span id="firstLine"><span  class="selectedOrderDetails"> 098209</span> <span class="selectedOrderDetails"> 14/12/2012</span> <span class="selectedOrderDetails"> 10/12/2012</span> <span class="selectedOrderDetails"> Yes</span> </span><span id="secondLine"><span class="selectedOrderDetails"> test </span> <span  class="selectedOrderDetails"> 10/12/2012</span> <span  class="selectedOrderDetails"> 14/12/2012</span> <span  class="selectedOrderDetails"> testType</span> </span>